# linq if statement, or stored procedure if statements

Tags: c#, c, linq, linq-to-sql

I am looking to run a piece of code in the database. However there is no supported translation to sql (using linq to sql).

How to convert this code logic ro either inline in linq or in a stored procedure?  I have no knowledge of db and stored procedures so preferably I would like to write it in linq.

```
public Post GetPageOwner(int pageid)
{

    var posts = (from dp in db.Posts where dp.pageid == pageid select dp);
    var returned = posts;

    if (posts.Count() > 0)
    {
        var latest = posts.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).FirstOrDefault();
        var sharedsamedayaslatest = (from p in posts where p.Date.AddDays(1) >= latest.Date select p);
        if (sharedsamedayaslatest.Count() > 1)
        {
            var followedpost = (from p in posts from s in db.Subscriptions where s.Subscriber == UID && s.Subscribedto == p.UserId select p);
            var count = followedpost.Count();
            if (count == 1)
            {
                returned = followedpost;
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                returned = (from s in followedpost let reposts = GetPostReposts(s.id) let rating = GetPostRating(s.id) let score = reposts + rating orderby score descending select s);
            }
            else
            { 
                //no follower shared this post so return the most liked
                returned = (from s in sharedsamedayaslatest let reposts = GetPostReposts(s.id) let rating = GetPostRating(s.id) let score = reposts + rating orderby score descending select s);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //no shares on the day the latest share
            returned = sharedsamedayaslatest;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //only one post
        returned = posts;
    }

    return returned.FirstOrDefault(); //order by userid gets a random one
}
```

Comment: I might be able to help you but I'll need more information. Please provide the table structure (including PKs and FKs) of every table related to your task and a pseudo-code logic of what you're trying to achieve (because I'm too lazy to try to understand it by reverse-engineering your code). Then I'll see if it can be written in a statement that linq-to-sql can translate to T-SQL.

Comment: Is the "piece of code in the database" SQL?

Comment: @MatteoMosca the logic itself can change. The idea is just to be able to use if statements within linq to run at the db for each row. so something like this (from t in db.table from m in db.table2 if t.count>1 select t else if t.count = 0 ( if m. id ==1 select m else select t)

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to reason in a procedural or sql way. Linq approach is different: it might be possible to do what you want, but not in the way you're thinking. But to be able to help you, I still need the stuff I requested.

Comment: posts.Count() is a heavy operation and not necessary in the if statement. Consider changing it to .Any()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this would work:

```
        public Post GetPageOwner(int pageid)
    {

        var posts = (from dp in db.Posts where dp.pageid == pageid select dp);
        var returned = posts;

        if (posts.Count() > 0)
        {
            var latest = posts.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).FirstOrDefault();
            var sharedsamedayaslatest = (posts.Where(p => p.Date.AddDays(1) >= latest.Date));
            if (sharedsamedayaslatest.Count() > 1)
            {
                var followedpost = (posts.SelectMany(p => db.Subscriptions, (p, s) => new {p, s}).Where(
                    @t => s.Subscriber == UID && s.Subscribedto == p.UserId).Select(@t => p));
                var count = followedpost.Count();
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    returned = followedpost;
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    returned = (followedpost.Select(s => new {s, reposts = GetPostReposts(s.id)}).Select(
                        @t => new {@t, rating = GetPostRating(s.id)}).Select(
                            @t => new {@t, score = reposts + rating}).OrderByDescending(@t => score).Select(@t => s));
                }
                else
                {
                    //no follower shared this post so return the most liked
                    (sharedsamedayaslatest.Select(s => new {s, reposts = GetPostReposts(s.id)}).Select(
                        @t => new {@t, rating = GetPostRating(s.id)}).Select(
                            @t => new {@t, score = reposts + rating}).OrderByDescending(@t => score).Select(@t => s)) = returned;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //no shares on the day the latest share
                returned = sharedsamedayaslatest;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //only one post
            returned = posts;
        }

        return returned.FirstOrDefault(); //order by userid gets a random one
    }
```

Comment: This won't ever be transalated by linq-to-sql. You need to write a linq (or lambda) query without if/else and variables. With proper table structure, FKs etc it *might* be possible, but as I stated, more info is required before attempting to write the linq/lambda statement.